# Gives error when running, but with bullet/break points not

Tags: java

I want to loop in my hashset with another hashset. It works when I use bullet/break points. But when I run it normale, it gives the following error:

`Delivery.java:44 =  Parcel entry = entryPackage.next();`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1495)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1516)
at Delivery.checkOrder(Delivery.java:44)
at Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

---

```
Iterator<Parcel> entryPackage = weightList.iterator();
while(entryPackage.hasNext())
{
    for(Deliverer deliverer : delivererlist)
    {
        Parcel entry = entryPackage.next();
        if(deliverer.getWeight() >= entry.getWeight())
        {
            String delivererName = deliverer.getName();
            String packageName = entry.getName();
            Postoffice.deliveryList.put(packageName, delivererName);
            deliverer.setWeight(deliverer.getWeight() - entry.getWeight());
            entryPackage.remove();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it runs when in debug? Because I'm pretty sure that if you bring it to completion (that is, you run *all* the iterations) it will fail anyway. `while(entryPackage.hasNext())` is not sufficient if you then ignore it in the innermost loop.

Comment: You may want to just hoist the `Parcel entry = entryPackage.next();` line outside the inner loop, depending on exactly what the requirements are...